# ios push notification server reliability

Tags: ios, ios4, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on app that has realtime components and I'm wondering if I can use apple's push notification service for this.

How many messages can we send? Can we use it for something like a chat service?

If not what are our alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple uses push notifications for their new chat service, so yes, you could use it for a chat service.

There are no good alternatives to push notifications. You'd have to manage your own socket and it would only work while your application is running.